# Understanding query variance in exec time in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql, benchmark

I want to execute a set of queries many times through psql and to study running/execution time of each query. Of course, I want to run them many times to reduce effect of external factors through statistical analysis, but I expect variance to be quite high because in my personal experience, 10 times that you run the same query, 3 or 4 of them I get a relatively lower absurd value.

So how can I track down or at least understand the nature of these external influences? I am making sure that all my data is in cache and I have nothing in background. But still seems like something is amiss.

Comment: Do you use parameters in those queries ? What difference did you notice in the EXPLAIN plans of the slow and fast queries ?

Comment: The plan is the same but the timing of some nodes is smaller... What kind of parameters are you referring to?

Comment: Are you using https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html ? You're talking of high variance... Is the query duration in ms, s, minutes ? You're saying that the plan is the same, but on which nodes of the plan do you see some difference ? Are your statistics up to date ? Try to post some numbers or code as otherwise we'll hardly do more than just guessing.

Comment: Yes statistics are up to date and the query is in the ms levels. It is a sensitive query in that sense and I was expecting this question to take a general approach/ high level overview- I would appreciate guessing.

Comment: Some of my questions remain... On which nodes do you see significant time difference ? Are you using prepared statements ? Which version of PostgreSQL are you using ? Some quite significant improvements were made regarding variance in 9.6. How is autovacuum configured ?